# Error trying to build a modified blender on windows

Tags: windows

I am trying to build this modified blender version from this repo
https://github.com/dzigaVertov/vertov_blender .

I found out that it is based on Blender 2.93 because it has the following code in the BKE_blender_version.h file:

```
#define BLENDER_VERSION 293
```

and uses precompiled libraries from that command:

```
svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-2.93-release/lib/win64_vc15/  lib/win64_vc15
```

I used visual studio community 2019 and cmake version 3.17.2

I managed to configure and generate the project with cmake gui as described in the Blender documentation ([Manual CMake setup](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Windows)), then I went into the build folder and typed the following line into cmd:

```
 cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release
```

But unfortutanly, I got warnings like this one:

```
cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/external:W3' with '/external:W0' [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\source\blend
er\compositor\bf_compositor.vcxproj]
```

And I got the following error at the end:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake [C:\Users\user\D
esktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxpr
oj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(155
,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [C:\Users\user\Desktop\b\kk\INSTALL.vcxproj]
```